# Relation between change in a series vs its average

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

***Part 1:***

Let $x$ be given by:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n  e^{-i  s_i} = \sum_{i=0}^n  e^{-i x}$$

where $0< \{s_k\} < 0.5 $ is a monotonically increasing sequence. So x is some kind of average of ${s_i}$

Now let $\{s_i\}$ change by a constant amount $ds$

$\{s_i\} -> \{s_i + ds\}$

Is the corresponding $dx$ smaller than, equal to, or larger than $ds$?

***Part 2:***

Let $0<c<50$ be a constant and $y$ be given by:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n c  e^{-i  s_i} + 100  e^{-ns_n} = \sum_{i=0}^n c  e^{-i y} + 100  e^{-n  y}$$

So y is another kind of average of ${s_i}$

Is the corresponding $dy$ smaller than, equal to, or larger than $ds$?